# Segue with confirmation dialog in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

SO,

**The problem**

In my storyboard, I have a segue that leads to some view (actually, it's a backward segue). In the same time, segue action is performing some irreversible things (some items deletions, for example), so I need to add confirmation dialog. It's not too hard to add with:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
[alert setTitle:[lang getLocalizedString:reg.language stringAtIndex:@"303"]];
[alert setMessage:[lang getLocalizedString:reg.language stringAtIndex:@"304"]];
[alert setDelegate:self];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:[lang getLocalizedString:reg.language stringAtIndex:@"305"]];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:[lang getLocalizedString:reg.language stringAtIndex:@"306"]];
[alert show];
```

(here `[lang getLocalizedString: ..]` are just localized strings).

But the thing is: I *can not* use standard `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` method with that. The desired logic should be:

```
+-------+     +-------+     +------------------------------------+
|  User |     |Trigger|     |Decision about segue will be made at|
|pressed| --> | segue | --> | shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier   |
| button|     | stuff |     | so trigger alert show inside it    |
+-------+     +-------+     +------------------------------------+
                                              |
                                              V
                                      +---------------+
                                      |  Show alert,  |
                                      | Yes/No buttons|
                                      +---------------+
                                         /         \
+-------+      +---------------+        /           \        +---------------+
|Finally|      |Segue action   |     +---+         +---+     | All canceled  |
|perform|  <-- |will be made in| <-- |Yes|         | No| --> |just do nothing|
| segue |      |prepareForSegue|     +---+         +---+     |  i.e. return  |
+-------+      +---------------+                             +---------------+
```

I hope it's clear. But here's where tricky part is: obviously, we can't "make a decision" in `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` based on user selection, since it will be executed asynchronously. So dialog will be shown, but method will continue it's execution, so then return `YES` or `NO` independently of dialog. There's a part of where's logic is breaking.

**My approach**

I was playing with it and trying different things (even went to `sleep` until some external pointer will be set to some value derived from user selection on dialog popup - with no success, of course). So now I can't implement logic that is in scheme above. Instead I've achieved desired behavior with following things:

1. Attached touch up inside action for button which is triggering segue.
2. Placed popup displaying into touch up inside action
3. Placed segue logic into section of popup that corresponds "Yes" selection
4. Placed *programmatically launching* of segue after logic. It's like:

   ```
       -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
       {
           if (buttonIndex == 0)
           {
               //"Yes" button pressed
               //...
               //Here is omitted part of segue logic
               //...
               [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"deleteUnwindSegue" sender: self];
           }
           else if (buttonIndex == 1)
           {
               //"No" button pressed, nothing to do
           }
       }
   ```
5. Method `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` is always return `NO` now.

This works well, but, however, I'm still wondering is the way like described in scheme above can be implemented, so, question is:

**The question**

- Is there a way to suspend somehow execution of method so it will wait for user action?
- May be there is another, better way to achieve desired behavior? Any comments of why this is good/bad will be welcome.

Comment: "do nothing" is on `Yes` or 'No`? check button index

Comment: It's on `"No"` button of course (that means user canceled action, so we'll stay on current view and do nothing)

Comment: you are performing segue in index==0 of `clickedButtonAtIndex delegate`...please confirm

Comment: Yes. Segue will be made on `Yes` button (and it has index `0`)

Comment: where you calling `alertView`? does your alertview is not waiting for user action?

Comment: @preetam it's called in button's touch up inside action (step `2`)

Comment: I think you have created segue from `button` that invokes alertView, create it from `viewControler`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the motivation behind calling segue related actions immediately after tapping the button (except for the fact that it's all configurable via storyboard). What I would do is trigger the alert as a result of tapping the button, then perform the transition to the next controller as a result of user input. Also, it would be more elegant to use a block-based `UIAlertView` (many are available online).

Good luck!

Comment: So you're saying that my current solution is as how it's intended to be?

Comment: What you're doing is okay - but as @Stavash says, you don't even need to trigger the segue initially. Instead, show the alertView when the user taps the button. Once you've checked the user has tapped the Yes button, *then* programmatically trigger the segue. That way, you don't even need to implement `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` for this segue.

Comment: @JamesFrost so I'm doing exactly this thing now. I.e. triggering segue programmatically (step `4` in solution). I don't get how to "not to do segue" - since segue is a part of storyboard and, thus, it must be present in order to I'll be able to use it

Comment: Well, it seems there are no other opinions. In any case, your answer was helpful, so than you for your time!